# How to write a simple warp handler returning json or html?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I have the following:

```rust
use warp::Filter;

pub struct Router {}

impl Router {
    pub async fn handle(
        &self,
    ) -> std::result::Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {

        let uri = "/path";

        match uri {
            "/metrics-list" => {
                let empty : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                Ok(warp::reply::json(&empty))
            }

            "/metrics-ips" => {
                let empty : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                Ok(warp::reply::json(&empty))
            }

            &_ => {
                Err(warp::reject::reject())
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let r = Router {};

    let handler = warp::path("/").map(|| r.handle());

    warp::serve(handler);
    // .run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 3000))
    // .await;
}
```

But even with this simplified example I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl warp::Future: warp::Reply` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:41:17
   |
41 |     warp::serve(handler);
   |                 ^^^^^^^ the trait `warp::Reply` is not implemented for `impl warp::Future`
   |
  ::: $HOME/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.2.5/src/server.rs:26:17
   |
26 |     F::Extract: Reply,
   |                 ----- required by this bound in `warp::serve`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `warp::Reply` for `(impl warp::Future,)`
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to call `.into_response()` on all your replies and then change the return type from `std::result::Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection>` to `std::result::Result<warp::reply::Response, warp::Rejection>`

```
pub async fn handle(
        &self,
    ) -> std::result::Result<warp::reply::Response, warp::Rejection> {

        let uri = "/path";

        match uri {
            "/metrics-list" => {
                let empty : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                Ok(warp::reply::json(&empty).into_response())
            }

            "/metrics-ips" => {
                let empty : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                Ok(warp::reply::json(&empty).into_response())
            }

            &_ => {
                Err(warp::reject::reject().into_response())
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason being if I understand this correctly that having an `impl Trait` in your return type lets you only use one type that implements that trait at once, since your function can ever only have one return type.